# UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I check out Apple's ScrollView suite example code. When i use it in my code then it not working while i had not made any change.I was just wondering how I cannot get a double tap to undo the zoom inside of a scroll view? I cant seem to figure it out. I am insert image from URL  while in the sample code drag a image in interface builder. I also try with same code but recognize of tap on image is not working. Why it happened i can not get it? I also show my code below:

```
- (void)loadView {
[super loadView];

// set the tag for the image view
[imageView setTag:ZOOM_VIEW_TAG];

// add gesture recognizers to the image view
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];
UITapGestureRecognizer *twoFingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTwoFingerTap:)];

[doubleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
[twoFingerTap setNumberOfTouchesRequired:2];

[imageView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:twoFingerTap];

[singleTap release];
[doubleTap release];
[twoFingerTap release];

NSURL *imgUrl=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.iso.org/iso/alan_bryden_larger.jpg"];                 
NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imgUrl];
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];

[self.imageScrollView addSubview:imageView];
[imgUrl release]; 

// calculate minimum scale to perfectly fit image width, and begin at that scale
float minimumScale = [imageScrollView frame].size.width  / [imageView frame].size.width;
[imageScrollView setMinimumZoomScale:minimumScale];
[imageScrollView setZoomScale:minimumScale];}
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
return [imageScrollView viewWithTag:ZOOM_VIEW_TAG];} 


 - (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale {
[scrollView setZoomScale:scale+0.01 animated:NO];
[scrollView setZoomScale:scale animated:NO];}

 - (void)handleDoubleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
// double tap zooms in
float newScale = [imageScrollView zoomScale] * ZOOM_STEP;
CGRect zoomRect = [self zoomRectForScale:newScale withCenter:[gestureRecognizer locationInView:gestureRecognizer.view]];
[imageScrollView zoomToRect:zoomRect animated:YES];}

 - (void)handleTwoFingerTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
// two-finger tap zooms out
float newScale = [imageScrollView zoomScale] / ZOOM_STEP;
CGRect zoomRect = [self zoomRectForScale:newScale withCenter:[gestureRecognizer locationInView:gestureRecognizer.view]];
[imageScrollView zoomToRect:zoomRect animated:YES];}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Your `UIImageView` won't pass touches to a `UIGestureRecognizer` unless you have set `userInteractionEnabled = YES`.

Answer (score 4):

You are adding gestures to imageView, then you allocating a new UIImageView and adding to scrollView. Thats the problem i guess. Rearrange your code as,

```
NSURL *imgUrl=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.iso.org/iso/alan_bryden_larger.jpg"];                 
NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imgUrl];
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
// set the tag for the image view
[imageView setTag:ZOOM_VIEW_TAG];

// add gesture recognizers to the image view
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];
UITapGestureRecognizer *twoFingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTwoFingerTap:)];

[doubleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
[twoFingerTap setNumberOfTouchesRequired:2];

[imageView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:twoFingerTap];

[singleTap release];
[doubleTap release];
[twoFingerTap release];

[self.imageScrollView addSubview:imageView];
[imgUrl release];
```

Comment: In addition to this, you should also consider downloading the image on the background and then add the image view to the scrollview. Since it seems to be static you might also consider saving the image to resources folder and then loading it.

Comment: @iAnand I do that but when i double click on image then it not work or  can not detect tap on image. Image can not zoom in or zoom out.

Comment: when run this i get message on console that is unable to acess single and double tap.  *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x4b4cc70 of class UIView autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking

Answer (score 2):

```
// try this code

#import "RootViewController.h"

#define ZOOM_VIEW_TAG 100
#define ZOOM_STEP 1.5


@interface RootViewController (UtilityMethods)
- (CGRect)zoomRectForScale:(float)scale withCenter:(CGPoint)center;
@end


@implementation RootViewController

@synthesize imageScrollView, imageView, mySlider;

- (IBAction) sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender {
    mySlider.value = [NSString stringWithFormat:imageScrollView.[sender value]];

     //mySlider.value = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %.1f", [sender value]];


    //myTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %.1f", [sender value]];
}


- (void)loadView {
    [super loadView];

    // set the tag for the image view
    [imageView setTag:ZOOM_VIEW_TAG];

    // add gesture recognizers to the image view
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *twoFingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTwoFingerTap:)];

    [doubleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
    [twoFingerTap setNumberOfTouchesRequired:2];

    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:twoFingerTap];

    [singleTap release];
    [doubleTap release];
    [twoFingerTap release];

    // calculate minimum scale to perfectly fit image width, and begin at that scale
    float minimumScale = [imageScrollView frame].size.width  / [imageView frame].size.width;
    [imageScrollView setMinimumZoomScale:minimumScale];
    [imageScrollView setZoomScale:minimumScale];
}


- (void)viewDidUnload {
    self.imageScrollView = nil;
    self.imageView = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [imageScrollView release];
    [imageView release];
    [super dealloc];
}

#pragma mark UIScrollViewDelegate methods

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return [imageScrollView viewWithTag:ZOOM_VIEW_TAG];
}

/************************************** NOTE **************************************/
/* The following delegate method works around a known bug in zoomToRect:animated: */
/* In the next release after 3.0 this workaround will no longer be necessary      */
/**********************************************************************************/
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale {
    [scrollView setZoomScale:scale+0.01 animated:NO];
    [scrollView setZoomScale:scale animated:NO];
}

#pragma mark TapDetectingImageViewDelegate methods

- (void)handleSingleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    // single tap does nothing for now
}

- (void)handleDoubleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    // double tap zooms in
    float newScale = [imageScrollView zoomScale] * ZOOM_STEP;
    CGRect zoomRect = [self zoomRectForScale:newScale withCenter:[gestureRecognizer locationInView:gestureRecognizer.view]];
    [imageScrollView zoomToRect:zoomRect animated:YES];
}

- (void)handleTwoFingerTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    // two-finger tap zooms out
    float newScale = [imageScrollView zoomScale] / ZOOM_STEP;
    CGRect zoomRect = [self zoomRectForScale:newScale withCenter:[gestureRecognizer locationInView:gestureRecognizer.view]];
    [imageScrollView zoomToRect:zoomRect animated:YES];
}

#pragma mark Utility methods

- (CGRect)zoomRectForScale:(float)scale withCenter:(CGPoint)center {

    CGRect zoomRect;

    // the zoom rect is in the content view's coordinates. 
    //    At a zoom scale of 1.0, it would be the size of the imageScrollView's bounds.
    //    As the zoom scale decreases, so more content is visible, the size of the rect grows.
    zoomRect.size.height = [imageScrollView frame].size.height / scale;
    zoomRect.size.width  = [imageScrollView frame].size.width  / scale;

    // choose an origin so as to get the right center.
    zoomRect.origin.x    = center.x - (zoomRect.size.width  / 2.0);
    zoomRect.origin.y    = center.y - (zoomRect.size.height / 2.0);

    return zoomRect;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to set the `userInteractionEnabled` property:

```
imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: Corrected the answer, makes sense now.